# Is it possible to embed an mp4 movie in an AS3 project? (no netstream)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, embedded-resource

I need to embed a movie file into an AS3 project and play it. I've only used NetStreams before, but since I want to have it as an embedded resource this time, that won't be necessary.

I know it's possible for MP3's and other resources, but can't find any clear info on video  like mp4.

It's hard to google the problem because of the ambiguity of the word 'embed'

Answer (score 1):

You can embed anything as binary data using metadata like this:

```
[Embed("file.mp4", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
```

And then you can get that data as ByteArray at runtime. So if you can use byte array for playback, then yes, it is possible.

Comment: Maybe this + `NetStream.appendBytes()` would work? The thing is MP4 is just a container, so it would depend if the codec is supported by Flash. I know for sure that MP4 + H264 works.